# Simple Replace function

Tags: parsing, excel, csv, delimiter, vba

Shown below is the bottom half of the query I'm working on. The query returns all the values I want, but CSV is breaking apart account names that include commas (e.g. Sales, General and admin) into multiple columns.

I started looking at VBA code a few weeks ago and despite finding numerous pages on the replace function, I couldn't figure out how to get it to run inside my code, specifically after the query and before the delimiter so that the account names are kept intact/separate from the data.

Account names are changed fairly frequently, so ultimately I need a code that allows me to either enter specific account names that include commas so the code knows to ignore those commas, or a parse type function. Thanks in advance.

```
QueryQuote:
         With Sheets("Income").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=Sheets("Income").Range("a1"))
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .SaveData = True
        End With


        Sheets("Income").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=Sheets("Income").Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
            Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

     Sheets("Income").Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 20
     Sheets("Income").Columns("B:L").ColumnWidth = 8


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a Text To Columns formula:

Sheets("Income").Range("a1").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns _ Destination:=Sheets"Income").Range("a1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
            TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, _
Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

The Comma:=True is what is separating your data.  Try changing that to false.

Answer (score 0):

Find and Replace:

```html
Cells.Replace What:="insert text here", Replacement:"insert replacement text here", _
LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

This is the vBA for the Find and Replace function. Use this for each phrase that needs to be found and replaced.

Comment: So I tried the find and replace function you provided, but it looks like the replacement function won't work whenever the csv is still strung together with commas. So in order to replace I'd have to list out (Sales, General and Administrative,50,20,80,55,60,20) and the numbers change depending on the company.

Comment: What end result are you trying to get? Are you wanting to replace the numbers with the name or vice versa?